# Last two items of a fragments Listview not showing when a footer is present

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview

Good day, I have an Activity which contains 4 fragments. The Activity has a footer which I use to switch between these fragment views. Now in one of my fragments, i have some widgets and the last widget is a `ListView`. The trouble am having is, the last 2 entries in the `Listview` are not displaying correctly! they are obscured by the footer. I have set my LayoutParameters for both the width and height of the `Listview` to `FILL_PARENT`. but its not working. Any idea how i can solve this?  Thanks in advance.

My Layout is :

for the fragment:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>  
    <RelativeLayout  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" 
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <Button android:id="@+id/line_button_id" android:layout_width="160dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" android:layout_marginLeft="5dp" android:focusable="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp" android:text="@string/line_graph" android:background="@drawable/temp_left_button" />

    <Button android:id="@+id/bar_button_id" android:layout_width="160dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/line_button_id"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/line_button_id" android:focusable="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true" android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:text="@string/bar_graph" android:background="@drawable/temp_right_button"></Button>"

    <FrameLayout 
       android:id="@+id/graph_framelayout_id"
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="280dp"
       android:layout_below="@id/line_button_id"
       android:padding="4dp"
       android:layout_margin="4dp"
       android:background="@drawable/rounded_date_filter">
    </FrameLayout>

        <!-- first cell information, dashboard -->
       <LinearLayout
             android:id="@+id/row1_id" 
             android:layout_width="fill_parent"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:layout_margin="4dp"
             android:layout_below="@id/graph_framelayout_id"
             android:orientation="horizontal"
             android:clickable="true"
             android:background="@drawable/rounded_table_row">

            <TextView 
                   android:id="@+id/dashboard_datefrom_id"
                   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                   android:layout_weight="1"
                   android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                   android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                   android:text="01 may 2012"/>

               <ImageView 
                   android:id="@+id/dashboard_image_id"
                   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                   android:layout_weight="1"
                   android:src="@drawable/ic_action_search"/>

                  <TextView 
                   android:id="@+id/dashboard_dateto_id"
                   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                   android:layout_weight="1"
                   android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                   android:text="01 sept 2012"/>
       </LinearLayout>

       <!-- accounts overview listview -->
        <LinearLayout 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/row1_id"
            android:layout_margin="4dp"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:background="@drawable/rounded_date_filter">

             <TextView 
              android:id="@+id/list_text_header_id"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:padding="2dp"
              android:text="@string/data_grid_text_header_day"
              android:background="@drawable/text_header">
              </TextView>

             <ListView
              android:id="@android:id/list" 
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="fill_parent">
             </ListView>

        </LinearLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>
```

and for the Activity i have this:

<

```
?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

 <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragment_container_id"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    </FrameLayout>

<include layout="@layout/footer"></include>"
</RelativeLayout>
```

i replace the fragments with in the framelayout of the Activity

Comment: What is the parent of listview? Paste your layout file

Comment: @vodich i have edited the question and included my layout

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What Layout are you using in your Fragment, this surely won't happen if you use RelativeLayout and set above attribute to your ListView like this :

Try to add this into FrameLayout in your Activity layout.

```
android:layout_above="@+id/footer"
```

Comment: with regard to the above, i had to add a LinearLayout with an id, put the included layout into this LinearLayout and then use the above answer on the LinearLayout.